# What difference does the colon make on an input statement?

Tags: format, sas

```
data test;
   input country $8. date mmddyy10.;
cards;
Germany 12/31/2000
France  01/31/2001
;
run;
```

In the 2nd line, can I use `input country $8. date : mmddyy10.;` ?

What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The colon will cause input statement to read from the first non-blank character on the line. Compare the next two data steps. The first will return a missing date for Germany, the second will contain 12/31/2000.

```
data test1;
   input country $8. date mmddyy10.;
cards;
Germany       12/31/2000
France  01/31/2001
;
run;

data test2;
   input country $8. date : mmddyy10.;
cards;
Germany       12/31/2000
France  01/31/2001
;
run;
```